# Include an icon/image inside Ant Design Collapse panel other than expandIcon

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm having issue adding icon in front of the `header title` as according to the [Ant design collapse docs](https://3x.ant.design/components/collapse/), we can only add `expandIcon` either on the right or left and I wonder if I can do both. But the icon I want to add is static which won't change when I clicked on panel to expand. Here's the picture to illustrate my [CustomCollapse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoHxc.jpg).

Here's my code of my collapse:

```js
//styled
const StyledCollapse = styled(AntCollapse)`
  &&& {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
    box-shadow: none;  
    background-color: #0e0304;
    .ant-collapse-content {
      background-color: #0e0304;
      color: #b5b5b6;
    }
    
    .ant-collapse-header {
      color: #b5b5b6;
    }
  }
  
`;

_______________________________________________________

<StyledCollapse accordian activeKey={props.show ? key : []} onChange={combineFunc}> 
      <AntCollapse.Panel
        {...props}
        header={props.header}
        showArrow={false}
        bordered={false}
        disabled={props.isFollowed}
        key={props.panelID}
        extra={
          <span>
            <div className={styles.extraContainer}>
              {
                !props.show && !props.isFollowed && props.panelID !== "1" && <img src={rewardIcon} alt="" style={{height:'1.2em', marginLRight:'10px', width:'auto', objectFit:'contain'}} />  // show this box
              }
              {
                props.show && !props.isFollowed && <img src={arrowDownIcon} alt="" style={{height:'1.2em', marginRight:'10px', width:'auto', objectFit:'contain'}} />  // show this icon
              }
              {
                props.isFollowed ? <img src={tickIcon} alt="" style={{height:'1.2em', marginLRight:'10px', width:'auto', objectFit:'contain'}} /> :  ""
              }
            </div>
          </span>
        }
      >
      {props.children}
      </AntCollapse.Panel>
</StyledCollapse>
```

In the `extra API`, I have added display of **+10**. So i'm wondering if I can still add an icon in front of the header title and what API should I use.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:
JSX return

```
function createMarkup() {
     return {__html: '<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a" /> abc'};
}

return (
   <Collapse defaultActiveKey={["1"]} onChange={onChange}>
      <Panel 
         header={<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />} 
         showArrow={false}
         key="1"
      >
        <p>123</p>
      </Panel>
   </Collapse>
)
```

result:

[image: two muppets]